# User Error Alert

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS2010 (with C#). I have an online application. I have 2 error forms setup that the user is redirected to if they encounter an error. I have a global.asax.cs file that i have code setup in the `Application_Error` event to send me an email to let me know a user has received an error. My issue is that I am receving an email every time the form loads. It should be only when an error occurs. Here is my code behind in the `global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() != null)
    {
        Exception myException = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        // Create the Outlook application by using inline initialization.
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));

        email.Recipients.Add(fake@fakeemail.com);

        email.Subject ="Error in COF page " + Request.Url.ToString();

        string message = string.Empty;

        message +="<b>Message</b><br />" + myException.Message + "<br />";

        message +="<b>StackTrace</b><br />" + myException.StackTrace + "<br />";

        message +="<b>Query String</b><br />" + Request.QueryString.ToString() + "<br />";

        email.Body = message;

        email.Send();

         //Clear out any lingering errors after they have been reported. 
        Server.ClearError();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend that you edit this method to write out logs(and disable email for a while) capturing the details of the error and sender. For some reason there are continuous errors in your application which can be found only by debugging

Comment: Thank you. I may do that until I ge the issue resolved. I am not sure what you mean by "continout errors in your application". I am not getting any errors when I debug my application.

Comment: since you are getting emails everytime the form loads, I am assuming that there is some ASP.Net error during a form load. That is what I meant by continuous error. Another possible cause could be that some code outside of the error handler may be sending the emails! Possible?

Comment: What is the error that you get when the form loads?

Comment: I should only get an email when the application encounters an error but i must have something setup incorrectly. I receive the email as soon as the application loads.